# Seifert matrices -- Figure 8 knot

Tags: knot-theory

I've just learnt about Seifert matrices and thought it might be a good idea to compute some. Can you tell me if this is right:

[image]

Here $x_1^+$ denotes the push off of $x_1$. I have omitted the diagram for $x_2$ since I think that it's the same as the one for $x_1$. For the linking number of $x_1$ and $x_2^+$ I seem to get $\mathrm{lk} (x_1, x_2^+) = 0 $ and similarly for $x_1^+$ and $x_2$. I think that's wrong but I'm not sure. The Seifert matrix I get is 
$$ S = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} $$

I found an example on the internet that gets Seifert matrix 
$$ S = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix} $$

But since a knot can have many Seifert surfaces there can be many different Seifert matrices so this doesn't tell me much.

Question 1: In general, how can I check that my Seifert matrix is correct?

Question 2: I think the process of constructing the Seifert surface is fiddly and hence error prone. Is there a neater way to compute the Seifert matrix of a knot? (I want to use the matrix to compute the Arf invariant)

Question 3: In the picture above I'm particularly unsure about picture 3. How do I know that I attached the bands correctly?

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:**

Assuming the other Seifert matrix is correct, my sums are wrong since mine gets me Arf invariant $1$ whereas the other matrix gives me Arf invariant $0$. Nonetheless, I'd be very grateful if someone could point out where my mistake is.

Comment: I just noticed that picture 3 is actually not quite right. But the idea behind it is, as you can see from picture 4 which should be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a partial answer, I can only help you with question 3, so here goes:

Basically, you messed up when you attached the bands. If you want to reduce the probability of ballsing up when constructing the Seifert surface I suggest that you try to make it look as close as possible to the original knot diagram. In the example of the figure 8 knot, this would mean that you should draw something like this:

[image]

Then you will see that you get 
$$ S = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} $$
which gives you $\mathcal{A} (q) = 0$ which is what you want.

Comment: You're the same user as the one who asked the question. Why are you referring to yourself as "you"?

Comment: Oops, must've taken the green pill instead of the red pill again. Multiple personality disorder and colour blindness do not mix well. But it explains why the headache went away.

Answer (score 1):

Your Seifert algorithm seems to have gone wrong: in the fourth step it seems as if the boundary of your surface is a link instead of a knot.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will have to look into it when I have more time.