# Seifert matrices and Arf invariant -- Cinquefoil knot

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, knot-theory

I have computed the following Seifert matrix for the Cinquefoil knot:

[image]

$$ S = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
        0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 &  1& 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

I also found a Seifert matrix for this knot [on the internet](http://oeis.org/A060884) but I [still](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190976/seifert-matrices-figure-8-knot) don't know how to verify the correctness of a Seifert matrix. Hence:

**Question 1**: How can I verify that a Seifert matrix that I computed is correct?

Now, more importantly:

I thought I could compute the Arf invariant as follows (where $K$ is my knot):

$$ A(K) = A(q) = q(x_1) q(x_2) + q(x_3) q(x_4) = 1 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 1 = 0$$

where $x_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, x_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, x_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} , x_4 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $q(x) = x^T S x$.

But this must be wrong for the following reasons: 1. Assuming the Seifert matrix I found on the internet is correct, I get the same Arf invariant. 2. The Arf invariant of the cinquefoil knot is $1$. 
3. "The Arf invariant is $0$ if a majority of classes have self-linking $0$, and is $1$ if most classes have self-linking $1$.". (Excerpt taken from [here](http://www.indiana.edu/~knotinfo/descriptions/arf_invariant.html)). The self-linking numbers are the diagonal entries of the Seifert matrix as far as I understand.)

**Question 2**: What is the correct way to compute the Arf invariant of a knot from a Seifert form / Seifert matrix?

Comment: It's knot obvious.

Comment: Can you please explain the algorithm you used in order to construct the spaning surface ? The known Seifert algorithm does not automatically gives a similar form as your surface which is actually just the standard compact closed suface with twisted handles. This form allows a facility when calculating the linkings between the generators. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes you think that $x_i$ form a symplectic basis for $S$? In fact they don't. Also, you don't want a symplectic basis for $S$ but rather for $I = S^T - S$.

Your Seifert matrix must be wrong since if I compute the Arf invariant using the $S$ with a symplectic basis 
$$ e_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\1 \end{pmatrix}
 e_2 = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\1 \end{pmatrix} 
  f_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\1 \end{pmatrix}
 f_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}$$  I get zero when I should be getting $1$.

Using the Seifert matrix you linked, 
$$ S = 
\begin{pmatrix} -1 & -1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

and a corresponding symplectic basis for
$$ I = S^T - S = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & 0 & -1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

$$ e_1 = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\1 \end{pmatrix}
 e_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} 
  f_1 = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\1 \end{pmatrix}
 f_2 = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}$$

yields
$$ A(K) = e_1^T S e_1 e_2^T S e_2 + f_1^T S f_1 f_2^T S f_2 = 7 \equiv_2 1$$
as expected.

Comment: Computed using [this online octave "terminal"](http://www.online-utility.org/math/math_calculator.jsp).

Comment: Of course, this matrix doesn't correspond to the Seifert surface in the drawing which is very unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica gives as `KnotData[]`:
`KnotData[{5, 1}, "SeifertMatrix"]`

`{{-1, -1, 0, -1}, 
{0, -1, 0, 0}, 
{-1, -1, -1, -1}, 
{0, -1, 0, -1}}`

Which is closer to the first "given" matrix.
The KnotData gives the arf invariant for that knot:

`KnotData[{5, 1}, "ArfInvariant"]`

`1`

I know that only gives Mathematica as the authority for the answers
but that is the best I can find.