# Showing pass equivalence of cinquefoil knot

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory

According to [C.C. Adams, The knot book, pp 224](http://books.google.com/books?id=M-B8XedeL9sC&lpg=PR1&ots=-U0K3a49a_&dq=colin%20adams%20pass%20equivalent&pg=PA227#v=onepage&q&f=false), "every knot is either pass equivalent to the trefoil knot or the unknot".

A pass move is the following: [image]

Can someone show me how to show that the [Cinquefoil knot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinquefoil_knot) is pass equivalent to unknot or trefoil? Been trying on paper but no luck. Don't see how pass moves apply here. Thanks.

Comment: Using Reidemeister moves would also be ok, have also tried that, also no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general method is demonstrated in Kauffman's book On Knots. Put the knot into a "band position" So that the Seifert surface is illustrated as a disk with twisted and intertangled bands attached. Then the orientations match those of your figure. You can pass one band over another. Your knot is the braid closure of $\sigma_1^5$. The Seifert surface is two disks with 5 twisted bands between them. Start by stretching the disks apart.

Comment: Thank you! You're my first answerer since I started to learn knot theory here on SE : ) Quite happy to have found you. I have uploaded a picture of my Seifert surface for the cinquefoil knot [in one of my previous questions here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191402/seifert-matrices-cinquefoil-knot). So, just to be sure, I should have kept the orientation in my third drawing then I'd've seen that I can for example swap the two non-twisted bands between the disks?

Comment: Yes, the diagram of the Seifert surface that you have should do the trick. I haven't worked this specific example though.

Comment: Also, I am quite busy this morning, so I won't check the details of your computations. Usually, it takes me at least 3 tries to get these things correct :/

Comment: Yes, I seem to struggle to get it right, too : /

Comment: I put a bounty on my other question.